# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile occured while trying to build recommendation engine of PredictionIO in Linux machine

Tags: linux, jar, sbt, predictionio

Error occured while trying to build the recommendation engine using PredictionIO. Please anyone know how to solve this issue.

```
root@testing:~/PredictionIO/engines# pio build --verbose
[INFO] [Console$] Using command '/root/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt' at the current working directory to build.
[INFO] [Console$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.
[INFO] [Console$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.9.4.jar is absent.
[INFO] [Console$] Going to run: /root/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency
[ERROR] [Console$] Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /root/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar
[ERROR] [Console$] Return code of previous step is 1. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 3):

For me help to download this file

> https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.7/sbt-launch.jar

Rename downloaded file to sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar and replace previous file in PredictionIO/sbt/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My issue was due to the issue of Java installation,    created a fresh copy of linux virtual machine and installed the PredictionIO. Now it is working fine.